# Integrated webcam listed as hidden device in Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam, dell-inspiron, device-manager

I have a [Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/inspiron-15-5000-series) laptop running Windows 10. A few days ago, the built-in webcam stopped working completely. Programs like [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/), [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), and [TestWebCam](http://www.testwebcam.com/) all fail to detect it.

[image: Skype fails to detect webcam]

At first, the camera appeared to be missing from Device Manager. However, after selecting ***View → Show hidden devices***, I found my Integrated Webcam listed  under ***Imaging Devices***.

[image: Integrated Webcam hidden in device manager]

I have tried all the steps from [Dell's official troubleshooting guide](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN85507/dell-webcam-and-dell-webcam-central-software-guide?lang=EN):

- Updating drivers for ***Integrated Webcam*** in *Device Manager* gave the message "The best drivers for your device are already installed."
- Uninstalling drivers for ***Integrated Webcam*** makes it disappear from *Device Manager* after rebooting.
- Updating to the [latest BIOS A12](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=GJ54M&fileId=3587834833&osCode=WT64A&productCode=inspiron-15-5555-laptop&languageCode=en&categoryId=BI) had no effect.
- Updating to the [latest Chipset 16.400.3601](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=7JN69&fileId=3681998559&osCode=WT64A&productCode=inspiron-15-5555-laptop&languageCode=en&categoryId=CS) seemed to have no effect, but bizarrely my AMD settings report version [16.40.3601-161206a-313192C-Dell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLyHK.png).
- [Dell's PC Diagnostics](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN298246/how-to-use-the-dell-pc-diagnostics?lang=EN) 40 minute scan didn't find any webcam related issues.
- [Access to the camera is enabled in Windows 10's privacy settings](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fixing-we-cant-find-your-camera-error-code-0xa00f4244/).

Comment: A device showing up as "hidden" like that typically indicates that it isn't currently connected. It's likely that you're looking at a hardware failure of some kind - either the internal connection to the webcam has been disconnected, or the webcam itself has failed in a basic way. Has the laptop recently been opened, serviced, or damaged (dropped)?

Comment: @Fopedush No damage or dropping as far as I can tell. I tried booting off a DVD to see if the webcam worked in Ubuntu, but the bios wouldn't let me use the CD drive as a boot option

Comment: You probably need to allow legacy boot in the BIOS.

Comment: I agree, this state means it’s disconnected. You can try looking at the laptop’s firmware (BIOS) setup, maybe there’s a switch.

Comment: Have you opened the laptop and disconnected the webcam to test? Then reattach and test again?

Comment: Is it deactivated in the BIOS?

Comment: If you bring up the device properties, go to the Details tab and drop down the Property list to show 'Has problem', is anything listed? Or do you just see "<false>"? And for Is Present and Is Connected, are both "<true>"?

Comment: @spikey_richie I unfortunately can no longer test this. I sent my laptop back to dell for repair.

Comment: How's the repair going? What's the status of this Q? Should it be closed / deleted?

Comment: I posted my check-list for when these DELL's fail at my work... hopefully it will help the next victim. Note that Step-1 for me is now always re-format it to Vanilla Windows 10 using the Microsoft Media Creation Tool.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing: Check BIOS**

<kbd>F12</kbd> on boot... `System Configuration` > `Miscellaneous Devices` > `Enable Camera`.

I have 35 of the the 13" ones. The commenters are correct that it is not normal for it to disable in device manager.
 I just got powershell to sweep the office DELL's:

- 15 listed the webcam as "imaging device".
- 20 listed as "Integrated Webcam".
- none disabled.

In fact, a quick visual shows that 4 users have a post-it stuck over it, so there maybe not be hardware/software key to disable it either... I usually re-format the DELLs to vanilla Windows 10 as soon as they hit my desk - all functions work... it will install as "Integrated Webcam" instead:

[image: Dell webcam running on default Windows drivers dating back to Vista]

You have done most of the right steps to check/resolve so far but I will re-iterate them here

**1. Ensure winver is 1709**
There was an issue just before Windows 12-month anniversary update called "webcam-gate" that blocked many 3rd party webcams. This shouldn't affect you as you are using the generic imaging-device drivers... but it's a no brainer to do the latest Windows 10 update anyway. The *Creator's Update* (v1709) solves a few other issues with "Exclusive mode" (where 1 app takes control of a device and no others can see it) so ensure you are up-to-date first.

**2. Dell's PC diagnostics on boot (F12)**
After the first set of tests (~7 minutes) you can say "no" to additional RAM tests... and then be presented with a results screen. It will indicate if Webcam was skipped or tested. please confirm.

**3. Check events for that driver**
Back in Windows, open device manager <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or right-click start and select "device manager"... double-click your device in question... choose tab "Events". You are looking for events where it started happening. Maybe a power event, or an insufficient resources clash. (you will need to scroll through a bunch of "device install requested" events from your recent tests.

**4. (Software Option) eat fresh**
 Uninstall it, (deleting the drivers) and try and get it to install `usbvideo.inf_amd64_06d8dbf36a7321ac`. This will make it pick up as a webcam, rather than imaging device. Failing that: Fresh install of Windows 10 by using the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool. The only thing from DELL you probably need is the DELL Update tool - and maybe DELL Software Delivery, if you want it to put that bloatware back on there (There are better free options, DELL just gets paid to shovel that onto your PC, which in turn keeps your purchase cost down... that's the only reason it's there). You don't need help+support. That is just a re-badged version of software called "PC-Doctor" and it allegedly causes issues with some PC-Security vendors (can provide sources if asked).

**4. (Hardware Option) Check connectivity as per comments**
This one takes a bit of guts, but it might be a fix (maybe you want to do software options first):

- Check USB Connector for Webcam

Before you start this - know that you WILL lose the magnets that help hold the lid closed. They are held in by hot-snot and will flick out easily. You can pop them back in loose, or just chuck them out.
 Flip over the PC undo the 10 screws on the backplate and pop it off, disconnect the battery and hold the power-button on the laptop to drain any residual electricity within. The internal USB ports are tiny. The webcam is top-right corner from memory. but just check those 2-3 ribbon cables are clipped in snug. The wide one is Video, the tiny one is webcam, and the medium one (~5mm wide) is the Windows button. If you have a touchscreen model I think it terminates there too.

- Pop open the screen.

See that ugly rubber seal running the edge of the screen? Stick a
   spudger (or plastic knife/wedge) between that and the plastic shell
   and pop it off carefully. Workshop manual says to un-bolt the 4
   hinge-anchors within the actual chassis first... but if you call them
   they say don't bother. just click that case off and check the cable
   running up to the webcam is still OK, and connected at both ends.

Comment: It's worth noting that driver dates all say they are Windows Vista, but they aren't necessarily... Microsoft just use that date so that literally ANY manufacturer ones released since the big OS-change will install over them by default. (Otherwise you get the issue where Windows-update and Dell update will fight forever swapping to their version of drivers)